# select all from two tables with sum cost

Tags: php, mysql

I try to select all from 2 tables in mysql database with the sum of total cost in the second table
i have a table name `tbl_project` contain

`db_id db_projectname` and other column

```
 1        test
 2        test2
 3        test3
```

second table name `tbl_activities` contain

```
db_id   db_projectname  db_totalcost
1        test            200
2        test            300
3        test2           800
```

the out put i want is

```
test  500
test2 800
test3
```

i try this query but it didn't give me that result

```
    select tbl_project.db_id, tbl_project.db_projectname,tbl_project.db_location,tbl_project.db_client,tbl_project.db_transferredto,tbl_project.db_psd,tbl_project.db_pdd,tbl_project.db_duration,tbl_project.db_past,tbl_project.db_padd,tbl_project.db_aduration,tbl_project.db_percent,tbl_project.db_pnote,tbl_project.db_user,tbl_project.db_cpercentage,tbl_project.db_epercentage,tbl_project.db_mpercentage,tbl_project.db_status,tbl_project.db_offer,tbl_project.db_sheet,tbl_project.db_invoice,tbl_project.db_po,sum(tbl_activities.db_totalcost) as total_cost from tbl_project,tbl_activities where 
tbl_project.db_projectname=tbl_activities.db_projectname
```

it give me 
test but sum of another project and only one project not all

Comment: There is a lot more fields being selected than in your required output - do you need all the fields selected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You needed to use `LEFT JOIN & GROUP BY`

```
SELECT
    tbl_project.db_id,
    tbl_project.db_projectname,
    tbl_project.db_location,
    tbl_project.db_client,
    tbl_project.db_transferredto,
    tbl_project.db_psd,
    tbl_project.db_pdd,
    tbl_project.db_duration,
    tbl_project.db_past,
    tbl_project.db_padd,
    tbl_project.db_aduration,
    tbl_project.db_percent,
    tbl_project.db_pnote,
    tbl_project.db_user,
    tbl_project.db_cpercentage,
    tbl_project.db_epercentage,
    tbl_project.db_mpercentage,
    tbl_project.db_status,
    tbl_project.db_offer,
    tbl_project.db_sheet,
    tbl_project.db_invoice,
    tbl_project.db_po,
    sum(
        tbl_activities.db_totalcost
    ) AS total_cost
FROM
    tbl_project
LEFT JOIN tbl_activities ON tbl_project.db_projectname = tbl_activities.db_projectname
GROUP BY tbl_project.db_id
```

---

**Note:**

Using `aggregate` function (e.g. SUM,COUNT..) without `GROUP BY` collapses the result set into a single row.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think you should GROUP BY 'db_projectname'. Because db_id is going to have more than one.

Answer (score 0):

try this;

```
SELECT 
db_projectname.db_projectname,SUM(tbl_activities.db_totalcost) AS total_cost 
FROM db_projectname
LEFT JOIN tbl_activities 
ON 
db_projectname.db_projectname = tbl_activities.db_projectname
GROUP BY db_projectname.db_projectname
```